# SignalR JS client: passing arguments to the invoke method

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'm trying to write a function inside an object `appHub` that will invoke methods on the server. Here is my code:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var appHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('appHub');

var appHub = {

     //some methods here

     invoke: function(){
        appHubProxy.invoke.call(arguments);
     }
}
```

As you can see, the `invoke` method should be called like this:

`appHub.invoke('serverMethod', arg1, ..., argN)`

I get this error when I run this code:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined

I tried `appHubProxy.invoke(arguments)`, it doesnt throw an error but of course, the server method is never called.

How can I pass arguments to SignalR's invoke method correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues:

1. when you use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) or [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), the first argument you need to pass is the context (the value for `this`)
2. if you want to pass arguments as an array, you need to use `apply` instead of `call`

In your code, you're calling the invoke method with an array as the context. The invoke method is looking for a nested property (maybe for `this.connection._`), which doesn't exist on the array, so that's why you get the error.

So you probably want to use this instead:

```
appHubProxy.invoke.apply(appHubProxy, arguments);
```

Comment: Thank you very much